# Setting Value of HTML5 currentTime audio does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I am trying to set the value of the `thisMusic.CurrentTime` to the calculation result that I get from the `console.log` part. Everything works fine and I get results as number perfectly in the log, but when I try to set the value of the calculation to the `thisMusic.CurrentTime` variable, it doesn't work, and when I `console.log(thisMusic.CurrentTime)`, I get `0` as result.

*Html*

```
<div class="row">
      <audio id="player-1" class="player" preload="none">
         <source src="/player/1.mp3 " type="audio/mpeg" codecs="mp3">
      </audio>
      <div class="progress timeline">
          <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-1" sub-id="1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var musics = $('.player');

   $('.play').click(function () {
     var thisMusic = musics[0];
     if (thisMusic.paused) {

          thisMusic.play();

          $('.timeline').click(function (event) {

                var duration = thisMusic.duration;    
                var clickPercent = ((event.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width());    

                console.log(parseInt(parseFloat(duration) * parseFloat(clickPercent)));  // Working.

                thisMusic.currentTime = parseInt(parseFloat(duration) * parseFloat(clickPercent));   // Not working, doesn't set.
           });

     } else {

            thisMusic.pause();

            $('.timeline').unbind('click');
    }
```

Comment: Try `thisMusic.get(0).currentTime = ...` - the currentTime attribute is a pure JS property and not a JQ object property.

Comment: When I use your suggestion, I get `Uncaught TypeError: thisMusic.get is not a function`

Comment: your file has no extension? Also, what is logged ?

Comment: Awh, yes - you are getting rid of the JQ object in `var thisMusic = musics[0];` , sorry for the misdirection. Another suggestion: you can move the `$('.timeline').click` event handler out of that conditional statement. On the same level `$('.play').click` handler is defined. If you really need to be aware of the what has happened in the main click handler - than create a boolean variable which is visible to both and use it for that.

Comment: @Kaiido Just fixed it. I edited the code to make it tidier here. When I console.log in the first place (where I commented 'Working', it is returning the second fine, but then when I try to set it to the `thisMusic.currentTime`, it doesn't work and `console.log(thisMusic.currentTime)` is returning `0`

Comment: @victor175 I also tried it outside of the `$('.play').click`. Still getting the same result :/

Comment: can u post a fiddle?

Comment: @senty It is a strange issue. I test your code and everything work !! All change I made is codec...

Comment: It was not so much regarding the problem, it is a better practice. The way it is - you are redefining that handler each time you go through that conditional. On your problem: consider that the audio must be ready to play when the `currentTime` is set.

Comment: I imported the code in jsfiddle and it worked fine for me too. It's probably that the audio is not ready thing.. Thanks

Comment: I post an answer to resume and close this question. Please make it to approved if it's good. Thanks

Comment: @Kaiido Ok I delete this "Not an answer" answer. But I can't see "Typo/Not Reproducible" flag reason when I want to flag the question.

Comment: @Kaiido It's good. I found it !

Comment: I found that it's not a problem was not related with jQuery but php instead. So I created another question (hoping it's not a duplicate) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730181/loading-mp3-files-and-setting-currenttime-for-html5-audio-tag-from-a-route . (also, received a minus point for some reason I couldn't figure out). Can you guys please take a look?